# Repeat table similar to repmat?

Tags: arrays, matlab

Looking for a command similar to repmat but for tiling tables instead of arrays.
My thinking is there might be a quicker/cleaner way than using a for loop.

Comment: Turns out there is. Cause tables are effectively arrays with named columns repmat can be used just like for an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tables are effectively arrays, so repmat can be used just like normally.